# Save array of images with Realm in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

okay, i have an app with 3 view controllers and in 2 of them i have 5 arrays of images. what i want to do is save each array of images using realm. the arrays are mutable and the user adds the images to the array of their choosing in vc1 and can send them to the arrays in vc2, but im not sure if i can just replace (in vc1) 
this:

```
var array: [UIImage] = [] {

    didSet{

        cView1.reloadData()


    }
}
```

with This:

```
dynamic var array: [UIImage] = [] {

    didSet{

        cView1.reloadData()


    }
}
```

i am also getting this error when i try to inherit RLMObject.
"multiple inheritance from classes uiviewcontroller and RLMObject"
here is my code

```
 class CViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, CDelegate , RLMObject
```

im fairly new to ios developing so any little bit helps thanks in advance

Comment: ClosetViewController is inheriting UIViewController and you are conforming to protocols by listing them after that. `RLMObject` should not be there at the end. You can think of `RLMObject` similar to how you would inherit from `NSObject`. Also in swift it's just called `Object`. The answer below is also a best practice way to save images.

Comment: it doesnt matter where i put Object on the line i still get the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting Object anywhere unless you've made a model class like Person, Dog, Article, etc. Those will initially inherit from NSObject in which you just replace NSObject with Object after adding `import RealmSwift` at the top

Comment: Hi user3462448, did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to save file path in DB, not image itself. So you need to create array of image paths instead array of images. Like this: `let images = List<String>()`

Also according to [Realm Docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) 'List' can't be dynamic:

> When added as a property on Object models, the property must be declared as let and cannot be dynamic.

And final, you must to inherit from 'Object', not 'RLMObject' and Realm class must be separate, like in this official example:

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var adopted: Bool = false
    let siblings = List<Dog>()
}
```

Comment: when i try to inherit from "Object" i get an error that says "use of undeclared 'Object'"

Comment: Are you doing import in the class file? `import RealmSwift`